# how to achieve drag and drop folder to some region or area in asp.net c# ..?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want o upload the folder to server .. 
for that when user drag and drop the folder the i will get the path at that time ui will zip it uploadedd to the folder..

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in html prior to version 5, which is fairly new and therefore not supported in most deployed browsers.  Your best bet right now is to use an add-in like silverlight, activex, flash, or java.